# Error establishing database connection when running mamp on port 80

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, mamp

I'm trying to run Mamp appache on port 80, because the application(wordpress MU) doesn't allow port-numbers in the domain-name.

When I run appache on the default MAMP-port, I manage to get a connection to the database, but when I run it on port 80, I get Error establishing database connection.

While on port 80, I have tried using both the default MAMP-port and default mySQL-port, I have also tried specifying the ports according to wordpress specifications, ie:

```
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8889');
```

Nothing of this makes any difference. I'm clueless what should I do?

Comment: the space after the ':' is intentional?

Comment: no, and not in the code either... by bad!

Answer (score 0):

When using MySQL port 3306,

[image: mamp ports]

this is the host: `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');`.

---

**Related**:

> [WordPress MultiSite Subdomains on MAMP](http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-subdomains-mamp/)
>   The easiest and recommended way of setting up WordPress MultiSite is to use sub-directories. So when you create a new site named “business”, it will be located at `http://localhost/business/`. Here’s a mini-tutorial on how to use *sub-domains* for your network sites.